# Printing status strings returned from an API

Tags: c

The Status code return by an API can be any of the following as per the document given by the vendor.

```
FTC_INVALID_HANDLE 
FTC_NULL_INITIAL_CONDITION_BUFFER_POINTER 
FTC_INVALID_NUMBER_CONTROL_BITS 
FTC_NULL_WRITE_CONTROL_BUFFER_POINTER 
FTC_INVALID_NUMBER_CONTROL_BYTES 
FTC_NUMBER_CONTROL_BYTES_TOO_SMALL 
FTC_INVALID_NUMBER_WRITE_DATA_BITS 
FTC_NULL_WRITE_DATA_BUFFER_POINTER 
FTC_INVALID_NUMBER_WRITE_DATA_BYTES 
FTC_NUMBER_WRITE_DATA_BYTES_TOO_SMALL 
FTC_NULL_WAIT_DATA_WRITE_BUFFER_POINTER 
FTC_NULL_OUTPUT_PINS_BUFFER_POINTER 
FTC_INVALID_INIT_CLOCK_PIN_STATE 
FTC_INVALID_FT2232D_CHIP_SELECT_PIN 
FTC_INVALID_FT2232D_DATA_WRITE_COMPLETE_PIN 
FTC_DATA_WRITE_COMPLETE_TIMEOUT 
FTC_INVALID_CONFIGURATION_HIGHER_GPIO_PIN 
FTC_FAILED_TO_COMPLETE_COMMAND 
FTC_IO_ERROR
```

In header file I found this:

```
typedef ULONG FTC_STATUS;
```

I want to print these strings. How do I use printf here?

```
FTC_STATUS Status;

printf("%...", Status);  //need help here
```

Comment: Chances are you'll have to write your own switch to map the ulong values back to strings unless the vendor provides one too. How are those constants defined - as #defines, as `const FTC_STATUS FTC_XXX = `, something else?

Comment: Do you want to print the **value** of the status code, or the **name** of it?

Answer (score 3):

If the status is a number starting with zero and incrementing by one for each status (i.e. `FTC_INVALID_HANDLE` is zero, `FTC_NULL_INITIAL_CONDITION_BUFFER_POINTER` is one, etc.), then you can put all strings in an array, and use the status code as an index into that array.

Something like this:

```
const char *status_codes[] = {
    "FTC_INVALID_HANDLE",
    "FTC_NULL_INITIAL_CONDITION_BUFFER_POINTER",
    /* etc. */
};

printf("Status is %s\n", status_codes[status]);
```

---

If that can't be done, then you could make a structure containing the status code and string for it, and then put these in an array. Then search this array for the status code until you find it, and use the string in the structure.

Something like this:

```
struct
{
    FTC_STATUS status;
    const char *name;
} status_name_map[] = {
    { FTC_INVALID_HANDLE, "FTC_INVALID_HANDLE" },
    { FTC_NULL_INITIAL_CONDITION_BUFFER_POINTER, "FTC_NULL_INITIAL_CONDITION_BUFFER_POINTER" },
    /* etc. */
}

/* Function to map a status to a name */
const char *find_status_name(FTC_STATUS status)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(status_name_map) / sizeof(status_name_map[0]); i++)
    {
        if (status == status_name_map[i].status)
            return status_name_map[i].name;
    }

    /* Status not found */
    return "<unknown>";
}

/* ... */

printf("Status is %s\n", find_status_name(status));
```

---

There is also a third way, to use a `switch` statement instead of manually searching though an array of structures (thanks [LtWorf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1827457/ltworf)).

Like this:

```
/* Function to map a status to a name */
const char *find_status_name(FTC_STATUS status)
{
    switch (status)
    {
    case FTC_INVALID_HANDLE:
        return "FTC_INVALID_HANDLE";

    case FTC_NULL_INITIAL_CONDITION_BUFFER_POINTER:
        return "FTC_NULL_INITIAL_CONDITION_BUFFER_POINTER";

    /* etc. */

    default:
        /* Status not found */
        return "<unknown>";
    }
}
```

---

The second and third way are safer, the second way is slower and uses more memory though. The third way should be both fast and use least memory (but more code).

Comment: A switch to replace the 2nd case would be better

Comment: @LtWorf Of course, think I need some caffeine or sugar (or both) now. :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to define an array for this purpose, containing the strings.

If I have to define such stuff, I prefer the following in order to keep the right order:

```
#define FOOLIST(x) \
    x(ABC) \
    x(DEF) \
    x(GHI) \
    x(JKL) \

#define FOOenum(x) FOO_ ## x,

enum FOO { FOOLIST(FOOenum), FOO_max }


#define FOOname(x) "FOO_" # x,
char * FOOnames[] = {
    FOOLIST(FOOname), NULL
}
```

This way I only have to add/remove/change something at one place and all dependent places are changed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
    char ch[MAXVALUE];
    switch(STATU_CODE_RETURNED_BY_API)
    {
        case FTC_INVALID_HANDLE :
            strcpy(ch,"FTC_INVALID_HANDLE");
            break;
        case FTC_NULL_INITIAL_CONDITION_BUFFER_POINTER :
            strcpy(ch,"FTC_NULL_INITIAL_CONDITION_BUFFER_POINTER");
            break;
        case FTC_INVALID_NUMBER_CONTROL_BITS :
        .
        .
        .
        .

    }
```

use ch while printing....

Comment: I think just using pointers to the string literals here would be more efficient.

Comment: Yes, you are right... He can use pointer instead of directly using the string in the switch statement.